# Fetching and Viewing data from firebase_database in Flutter as PDF

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fetching data from firebase_database so can view it as PDF from my dashboard screen. The issue when i try to use value to check if dataSnapshot.value is null get an error on value itself. How do i fix this issue? Have the right packages. Please advice me so can continue with my use case.

// packages

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dashboard'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
              onPressed: () {
                _signOut(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountEmail:
                    Text(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email ?? ''),
                accountName: Text('User'),
              ),

              ListTile(
                title: Text('Logout'),
                onTap: () {
                  _signOut(context);
                },
              ),

              // button to view data from database.
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _viewPDF();
                },
                child: Text('View PDF'),
              ),

              // button download pdf file
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _downloadPDF();
                },
                child: Text('Download PDF'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
       
// viewing the pdf data from firebase_database
 Future<void> _viewPDF() async {
    final user = _auth.currentUser;
    if (user == null) {
      return;
    }

    final dataSnapshot = await _databaseReference
        .child('quotes')
        .orderByChild('email')
        .equalTo(user.email)
        .limitToFirst(1)
        .once();


//The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'DatabaseEvent'.
Try importing the library that defines 'value', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'value'.dartundefined_getter
Type: InvalidType

    if (dataSnapshot.value(error) != null) {
      // Retrieve the first quote data based on the email
      final Map<dynamic, dynamic> quoteData = dataSnapshot.value;
      final firstQuote = quoteData.values.first;

      // Create a BusinessModel instance from the retrieved data
      final businessModel = BusinessModel.fromMap(firstQuote);

      // Generate PDF using businessModel
      final pdf = generatePDF(businessModel);

      // Save the PDF to a temporary file
      final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      final filePath = '${tempDir.path}/example.pdf';

      final file = File(filePath);
      await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());

      // Open the PDF for viewing
      OpenFile.open(file.path);
    } else {
      // Handle the case when no data is found for the user.
      // You can show an error message or take appropriate action.
      print('No data found for the user.');
    }
  }
}
```